# Passing a WCAG 2.0 (Level AA) test for a website

Tags: wordpress, wcag2.0, wpbakery

I am trying to pass a WCAG 2.0 (Level AA) in a website and I can't understand what should I change.
It gives me 2 errors.
The first error is :

> "Modify the header levels so only an h3 or any header less than h3
> follows h2."

This is in the footer of the webpage which has 4 columns. All columns are h2 but it always shows me an error in the last one.

The second is a little complicated.

The error is :

> "Modify the id attribute value so it is unique."

I have changed the id from page-id-44420 to page-id-12345 and it still gives me the same error.
The website is in wordpress and the link is https://www.ferkonal.gr/

The website that I check WCAG is https://achecker.achecks.ca/

Comment: Note that if you are **only** using a scanning tool and are not doing any manual accessibility testing, then even if the achecker tool says there are no issues, there will most likely be other errors the tool couldn't find.

Comment: Looks like a bug in achecker. All the <h2> headings in the footer are fine. They don't have to be <h3>.

Comment: I ran https://validator.w3.org/nu/ on your page and didn't see any duplicate ID issues.

Comment: @slugolicious The problem was with the template. It made changes when the menu was created. I change many things in the template and in functions.php to fix the errors